# Deleting rows from multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to delete a project from the `projects` table and all the images associated with that project in the `images` table.

Lets say `p_id = 10`

```
DELETE FROM projects, images WHERE projects.p_id = ? AND images.p_id = ?
```

What is wrong with this query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DELETE projects, images 
FROM projects, images 
WHERE projects.p_id = ? 
AND projects.p_id = images.p_id;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DELETE FROM projects, images WHERE projects.p_id = ? or images.p_id = ?
```

When being deleted, an item will never meet both of these requirements, therefore it must be `OR` not `AND`

Comment: +1 for catching the problem... I suggest using the `JOIN` syntax for a multi-table `DELETE`, which would have avoided such an ambiguity.

Comment: here i got this to work (i had to list tables after DELETE)
DELETE projects, images FROM projects, images WHERE projects.pr_id = '$del_id' AND images.pr_id = '$del_id'

Comment: That last comment will delete everything from those tables

Answer (score 4):

As [Chacha102 noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567976/deleting-rows-from-different-tables/2568001#2568001), the problem of your query was the `AND` in the `WHERE` clause.

However, you may want to use the `JOIN` syntax for multi-table `DELETE`s, which I find easier to read:

```
DELETE     projects, images
FROM       projects 
LEFT JOIN  images ON images.p_id = projects.p_id
WHERE      projects.p_id = 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

## The answer

```
DELETE FROM p, i
USING projects p, images i
WHERE p.p_id = ?
  AND p.p_id = i.p_id
```

## The test

### projects

```
create table projects (
  p_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key
);
insert into projects (p_id) values (1),(2),(3);
select * from projects;
-- +------+
-- | p_id |
-- +------+
-- |    1 | 
-- |    2 | 
-- |    3 | 
-- +------+
```

### images

```
create table images (
  i_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  p_id int unsigned default null
);
insert into images (p_id) values (1),(1),(1),(2),(2),(3),(3);
select * from images;
-- +------+------+
-- | i_id | p_id |
-- +------+------+
-- |    1 |    1 | 
-- |    2 |    1 | 
-- |    3 |    1 | 
-- |    4 |    2 | 
-- |    5 |    2 | 
-- |    6 |    3 | 
-- |    7 |    3 | 
-- +------+------+
```

### the delete

```
delete from p, i
using projects p, images i
where p.p_id = i.p_id
 and  p.p_id = 1;
```

### the result

```
select * from projects;
-- +------+
-- | p_id |
-- +------+
-- |    2 | 
-- |    3 | 
-- +------+

select * from images;
-- +------+------+
-- | i_id | p_id |
-- +------+------+
-- |    4 |    2 | 
-- |    5 |    2 | 
-- |    6 |    3 | 
-- |    7 |    3 | 
-- +------+------+
```

### works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

You should use two separate queries to do that :

```
delete from images where p_id = 123;

delete from projects where p_id = 123;
```

i.e. :

- First, delete the images, that depend on the project *(foreign key ? )*
- And, when nothing depends on the project anymore, delete the project itself.

And, as a security precaution, you should wrap all this in a transaction, to get a all or nothing behavior -- well, if you are using a storage engine that suppors transactions, like InnoDb.

See [12.3.1. START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, and ROLLBACK Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html), about that, in the MySQL Manual.

Answer (score 0):

Change the AND into an OR.

You might want to use a foreign key constraint with a cascading delete, much easier, but you have to use innoDB and create this FK-constraint. Delete the project and all related images will be deleted as well.

Answer (score -1):

(Wrong answer, [MySQL allows this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html))

You can't delete from two tables in one query.

The closest you can get is wrap the two deletes in a transaction:

```
begin transaction
delete from projects where p_id = ?
delete from images where p_id = ?
commit transaction
```

Comment: This is only allowed if the table is INNODB.

Comment: @Andomar, you certainly **can** delete from more than one table in a single query. My answer provides an example specifically for you.

Comment: @Smotchkiss: the first line of my answer says the answer is wrong, so I had figured that one out :)

Comment: my mistake. I thought that was in reply to someone else's answer.