# Error on SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete from multiple tables in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql)

i have a SQL query as follows

```
$deletebills=mysql_query("delete from bills,billsitems,cashier_trans where bills.bills_ID=billsitems.billsItems_BillItemSerial and bills.bills_ID=cashier_trans.cashier_trans_DocId and bills.bills_ID='".$_REQUEST['bills_ID']."'");
```

The Error :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where bills.bills_ID=billsitems.billsItems_BillItemSerial and bills.bills_ID=cas' at line 1

how can i solved it.

Comment: You're missing a FROM clause.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567976/deleting-rows-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql

Comment: Use DELETE FROM ... USING. And be careful to SQL Injection your code is not secured at all this is scary.

Comment: @Brendan Long but your link not solved !!

Comment: @Prash i am use from clause, see my code plz `delete from bills,billsitems,cashier_trans where bills.bills_ID=billsitems.billsItems_BillItemSerial and bills.bills_ID=cashier_trans.cashier_trans_DocId and bills.bills_ID='".$_REQUEST['bills_ID']."'`

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to delete from multiple tables at once, and the question I linked to gives the solution (do the queries separately). What you're trying to do isn't possible in MySQL.

Comment: So how can edit on my code what can i do ??

Answer (score 4):

You can't delete from all tables at once. You must delete from each table. [MySql Delete](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)